# jenkins Running jobs based on packages available

Tags: maven, testing, junit, jenkins, jobs

i have test packages like

```
test.regression.pacakgea
test.regression.pacakgeb
test.regression.pacakgec
```

these packages are developed by different people and am running them on VMs. i have configured an email notification for success and failures for each job. people may not be interested in going thru the mail for all the failures to find out which of their tests failed. the tests  inside the packages extend junit and am using maven as a build tool
so is there a way in which jenkins can execute each package as a separate job. i can make each pacakge into a different project and in jenkins i can configure this as a new job but thats too tedious as everyone has to checkin into 2 locations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Maven:

1. Make a Maven profile for each package you want to test.
2. Configure the Surefire plugin to [only include the packages you want to test in that build](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) using a variable from that profile.
3. Create a different Jenkins Job for each build with one of the three profiles.

Now Jenkins will test only that package in the given class.

Note that the include/exclude only works for the test packages. Those test might test code outside of that package.